# Example of parallel test execution using Mocha.js programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have been using Mocha.js through the cli for some time now and I am very used to it.

However, I have hit a few roadblocks that force me to start using Mocha.js programmatically. Mostly related to some specific reporters I want to use that don't play nice with CLI options.

Most things seem pretty clear. But I had a few tests that I executed in parallel via CLI using the `--parallel --jobs 6` options.

I am unable to accomplish this programmatically using Mocha. I found the ParallelBufferedRunner documentation on Mocha's official docs. However, with no example, I was unsure of how to use it properly.

There seems to be a general lack of examples and how-tos for using Mocha programmatically, which is quite discouraging.

Here is my attempt:

```
const Mocha = require('mocha'),
  Suite = Mocha.Suite,
  Runner = Mocha.Runner,
  Test = Mocha.Test

const mocha = new Mocha({
  reporter: 'spec'

});

mocha.parallelMode(true)

mocha.addFile('/Users/xxx/Repos/api-test-automation/test/regression-ui.spec.js');
mocha.addFile('/Users/xxx/Repos/api-test-automation/test/regression-backend.spec.js');

mocha.run(function (failures) {
  process.exitCode = failures ? 1 : 0; 
});
```

This doesn't seem to execute the tests in parallel. Also, I don't know how I would tell Mocha to only use 6 parallel executions.

I would greatly appreciate an example that is a bit more in-depth or pointers to the relevant info.

The Mocha API documentation is very rudimental.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha runs tests in parallel by spawning child processes. As such you will need to await the mocha run.

To specify the job count, you can pass it as an option when instantiating mocha. See [this link](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha)

The code would look like :

```
const mocha = new Mocha({
  reporter: 'spec',
  jobs: 6
})

// add files etc

await Promise.all(
  mocha.run(
    (failures) => 
        process.exitCode = failures ? 1 : 0
))
```